# can't use my function for viewdidload Use of unresolved identifier 'getSegue' swift

Tags: swift

cant call func for viewdidload

[CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zu854.png)

Use of unresolved identifier 'getSegue'

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! konuCell

    func getSegue() {

        cell.dersAdiLabel.text = gelenDersAdi

    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: copy/paste not only screenshot. `getSegue()` is wrongly written INSIDE `cellForRow:`. Check the bracklets ;) And what you want to do shouldn't be done like this. What is the goal of that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Basically,** You written your function in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` this will call nested Function but you have to write this at class scope.

**In short** write`getSegue()` function at class level scope just like that:

```
func getSegue() {

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! konuCell
    cell.dersAdiLabel.text = gelenDersAdi
    return cell
}
```

Comment: doing so will give an error Use of unresolved identifier 'cell'

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

To access `getSegue`, move it outside the scope of `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`, e.g.:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    [...]
}

func getSegue() {
    [...]
}
```

...but since `getSegue` would require a cell that it can modify, this is not going to work the way you want. I'd suggest keeping the code in `cellForRowAt` and reload the table view in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: doing so will give an error Use of unresolved identifier 'cell'

Comment: Of course it's unresolved. `cell` is an argument in `cellForRowAt`. Read the last piece of my answer.